# How to avoid word token when covert a dataframe into corpus?

Tags: text, token, cjk, corpus, quanteda

I try to convert a dataframe into a corpus for Chinese materials. I have utilized JiebaR to split
and tokenlized the text and then use the order

## corpus1 = corpus(dataframe)

While after this process, when I try to formulate the datatermmatrix, I find the some Chinese words have been split into single character. I want to know the reason and how to fix it. Thank you so much!

Comment: you need to provide some workable examples.

Comment: There should be no need to tokenize your text before constructing a corpus, as **quanteda** can tokenize Chinese pretty well. (See https://quanteda.io/articles/pkgdown/examples/chinese.html) . Or if you have already tokenized it into a list of tokens (one list element per document), convert it to a **quanteda** `tokens` object using `as.tokens()`.